# JSON to Embed Discord.PY

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I'm currently writing a bot in discord.py and I need some help with making the JSON response into an embedded message that the bot sends. Here's the code:

````
import discord

import requests

import json

from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot("!")

client = discord.Client()

url = "https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/collections/angomon"

response = requests.get(url)

json_response = response.json()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('test'):
        await message.channel.send(f'```{response.json()} ```')


@bot.command()
async def displayembed():
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Test',
        colour = discord.Color.blue()
    )

    embed.set_footer(text='Test')

    embed.add_field(name='Details', value = response, inline=False)
    
    await client.say(embed=embed)

@bot.command(name='list')
async def cmd_list(ctx):
    with open(response.json(), 'r') as read_file:
        users = json.load(read_file)

    embedlist = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='User List')

    embedlist.add_field(name='User Name', value=join(users.values()))
    embedlist.add_field(name='User ID', value=join(users.keys()))
````

When running the code, I get:

```
{'symbol': 'angomon', 'candyMachineIds': ['Exwuvrjz11h3pXgEt7AiYGRTstTcVhtBFhmbWGY9K569', '58Z9dKEcr9V6EPMWRnTzUzV8vtvURcgg1DsM9duLDnUW'], 'name': 'Angomon', 'image': 'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/4a51d0f3422fa43b3fae90c20cb11a48/88cf3e7e', 'description': 'Angomon are 3500 snazzy inhabitants of the Angoverse', 'createdAt': '2021-11-20T18:20:11.637Z', 'enabledAttributesFilters': True, 'hasAllItems': False}
```

I want to change all that JSON into a nice and organised embedded message. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What should the result look like for that specific output? We can't decide the problem specifications for you. If you want to chat with people to figure out a *design*, then you need a *discussion forum*, which this is not. Consider trying Reddit or Quora.

Comment: Command `response.json()` convert JSON string to PYthon data (like list, dictionary` and when you use `f-string` then you convert Python data to string. If you want format it then you could use `json.dumps(data, indent=2)` to convert Python data back to JSON string. Or use modules like `pprint` (`pretty print`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command `response.json()` converts `JSON string` to `Python data` (with `list`, `dictionary`, etc.) and when you use `f-string` then it convert `Python data` to `string` using standard method.

If you want format it then you could use `json.dumps(data, indent=2)` to convert `Python data` back to `JSON string`.

```
data = {'symbol': 'angomon', 'candyMachineIds': ['Exwuvrjz11h3pXgEt7AiYGRTstTcVhtBFhmbWGY9K569', '58Z9dKEcr9V6EPMWRnTzUzV8vtvURcgg1DsM9duLDnUW'], 'name': 'Angomon', 'image': 'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/4a51d0f3422fa43b3fae90c20cb11a48/88cf3e7e', 'description': 'Angomon are 3500 snazzy inhabitants of the Angoverse', 'createdAt': '2021-11-20T18:20:11.637Z', 'enabledAttributesFilters': True, 'hasAllItems': False} 

import json

text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

print(text)
```

Result:

```
{
  "symbol": "angomon",
  "candyMachineIds": [
    "Exwuvrjz11h3pXgEt7AiYGRTstTcVhtBFhmbWGY9K569",
    "58Z9dKEcr9V6EPMWRnTzUzV8vtvURcgg1DsM9duLDnUW"
  ],
  "name": "Angomon",
  "image": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/4a51d0f3422fa43b3fae90c20cb11a48/88cf3e7e",
  "description": "Angomon are 3500 snazzy inhabitants of the Angoverse",
  "createdAt": "2021-11-20T18:20:11.637Z",
  "enabledAttributesFilters": true,
  "hasAllItems": false
}
```

---

Or you could use modules like `pprint` (`pretty print`).

```
data = {'symbol': 'angomon', 'candyMachineIds': ['Exwuvrjz11h3pXgEt7AiYGRTstTcVhtBFhmbWGY9K569', '58Z9dKEcr9V6EPMWRnTzUzV8vtvURcgg1DsM9duLDnUW'], 'name': 'Angomon', 'image': 'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/4a51d0f3422fa43b3fae90c20cb11a48/88cf3e7e', 'description': 'Angomon are 3500 snazzy inhabitants of the Angoverse', 'createdAt': '2021-11-20T18:20:11.637Z', 'enabledAttributesFilters': True, 'hasAllItems': False} 

import pprint

text = pprint.pformat(data, indent=2)

print(text)
```

Result:

```
{ 'candyMachineIds': [ 'Exwuvrjz11h3pXgEt7AiYGRTstTcVhtBFhmbWGY9K569',
                       '58Z9dKEcr9V6EPMWRnTzUzV8vtvURcgg1DsM9duLDnUW'],
  'createdAt': '2021-11-20T18:20:11.637Z',
  'description': 'Angomon are 3500 snazzy inhabitants of the Angoverse',
  'enabledAttributesFilters': True,
  'hasAllItems': False,
  'image': 'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/4a51d0f3422fa43b3fae90c20cb11a48/88cf3e7e',
  'name': 'Angomon',
  'symbol': 'angomon'}
```

---

Or you should write own code to format it on your own.